# convert string to time and parse in golang

Tags: go

I'm reading a timestamp from a file, and I assign the value to `t`:

`t := "2016-11-02 19:23:05.503705739 +0000 UTC"`

When I attempt to parse the string:

`time, err := time.Parse("2016-11-02 19:18:57.149197306 +0000 UTC", t)`

The result is:

`0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC`

But I expected result to be:

`"2016-11-02 19:18:57.149197306 +0000 UTC"` ?

Please advise.

Comment: Was `err` nil? Gotta start by checking if `err == nil` and if false, what the contents of `err` are.

Comment: err is parsing time "2016-11-02 19:35:35.173585795 +0000 UTC": month out of range

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16536216/time-parse-behaviour, and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31070301/time-parse-with-custom-layout, and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18927725/strange-behavior-in-time-parse-function-in-go, and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25845172/parsing-date-string-in-golang/25845327, etc...

Comment: I've read those @JimB ... evans explanation below helped a lot to clarify how the layout string is constructed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not correctly providing the `layout` argument to `Parse`. You're supposed to be using `Mon Jan 2 15:04:05 MST 2006` (this is magic value, you put create a string in the format you want but with that date) in the given format so in your case, it would be `2006-01-02 15:04:05.000000000 +0000 UTC` plus the offset which I don't know off the top of my head for MST.

Comment: This is what I was trying to understand regarding the format string. Let me give this a try and I will come back shortly

Comment: @Mike sounds good. That aspect of the time package is a little weird thought it's pretty easy to work with once you get used to it. I believe your offset would be `-7` btw.

Comment: I'm still getting an error, I've uploaded the code here: https://play.golang.org/p/SPIMTX2jL4

Comment: @Mike that's because your `layout` argument still had the 2016 date when it's supposed to be based on that epoch of Jan 2nd 2006. Here's a modified example that works; https://play.golang.org/p/QRrel6YSkC

Comment: @Mike for that, your goal is to look at the format of your input time, then take that epoch (1/2/2006), and represent it in the format your input time is in.